# combining output of a query

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am fetching data from 3 tables with the help of join. My output is in JSON format.

***Output in JSON format:-***

{"order_id":"2","location_address":"Testing location Delhi","emp_first_name":"**Ranjeet**","order_status":"0","from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","actions":"\r\n </i> Edit </a>\r\n \r\n </i> Delete </a>"},

{"order_id":"2","location_address":"Testing location Delhi","emp_first_name":"**abhijeet**","order_status":"0","from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","actions":"\r\n </i> Edit </a>\r\n \r\n </i> Delete </a>"},

The problem is, In above output, All the data is same but emp_first_name are different because both are having seperate id's. Now i want to combine the data of both the emp_first_name and display it as single output like

***The output which i want :-***

{"order_id":"2","location_address":"Testing location Delhi","emp_first_name":"**Ranjeet,abhijeet**","order_status":"0","from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","actions":"\r\n </i> Edit </a>\r\n \r\n </i> Delete </a>"},

***QUery I Used :-***

```
$this->datatables->select('o.order_id, concat_ws(" " , `l.location_street`, `l.location_city` ) as location_address, e.emp_first_name, o.order_status, o.from_date')
   ->from('orders o')
   ->join('location l', 'o.location_id = l.location_id')
   ->join('order_details od', 'od.order_id = o.order_id')
   ->join('employee e', 'e.emp_id = od.emp_id');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can do it with php.decode the json and marge the emp_frist_name and encode again if you need it json format.